# How to get the selected value from dropdown list in PHP?

Tags: php

I am not able to retrieve the selected dropdown value to the PHP variable

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="#" method="post">
<select name="Color">
<option value="Red">Red</option>
<option value="Green">Green</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
<option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>    
</form>
<?php
$selected_val = $_POST['Color'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: What is actually happening? Nothing showing or?

Comment: You are missing submit button.

Comment: your going to get errors as your not checking anything has been posted before processing that

Comment: you must send this values with method post somewhere and then in this file retrive post. for example make button with `type="submit"` and change `action="$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']"`

Comment: I need to display the content without the submit button. And yes, nothing is showing.

Comment: Then use javascript, php is language that worked on server side.

Comment: do u have atleast a submit button to...submit this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use javascript for this, I give you simple script that will get for you value of selected option. Function load when user change value on select.

Take a look:

```js
function run() {
    document.getElementById("resultColorValue").innerHTML = document.getElementById("Color").value;
}
```

```html
<p>Choose your Color:</p>
<select id="Color" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="red">Red</option>
     <option value="green">Green</option>
     <option value="blue">Blue</option>
     <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>     
</select>

<p>Your color is: </p><p id="resultColorValue"></p>
```

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use multiple

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  <select name="Color[]">
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
   <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     foreach ($_POST['Color'] as $select)
     {
       echo $select;
     }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do this without the submit button in PHP? As I need to change the form according to my selection in the dropdown list.

Comment: @seno71625 - No, there is not.  You're mixing two ideas: server-side script (PHP) which can only respond to things *sent to it* (via the form submit), and client-side script (such as javascript) which would be able to watch / detect changes on the form while in the browser, without submitting the form.

Comment: there is only way, doing it without submit is `Jquery`. you can set <form onSubmit="return false;" and add a onClick event to any button and call your jquery submit. But after all, you must submit :)

Comment: better way and easiest is look at angular, this is javascript framework and you will find there everything you want (live changes on client side without submit form)

Comment: I am using angular since 2012. Angular is not good option for the OP, because he is a beginner as far as I see, he needs some HTML,JS background for it I guess.